# Find a Möbius Transformation fixing

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Find a Möbius transformation fixing 1 and sending 0 and i to -1 and i, respectively.

I was given this question and have absolutely no idea how to start.

Answer (score 1):

What form does a Möbius transformation take? Start with the general form, set one of the leading coefficients (in the numerator or the denominator) equal to $1$, and then use the fact that you want $f(1)=1,$ $f(0)=-1,$ and $f(i)=i$ to find the rest of the coefficients.

Comment: The process of how this is done is tricky, though. It would be nice to see it actually worked out.

Comment: Well, how would you start?

Comment: I think you know. take the formula $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, plug in $f(1)=1$ to get $f(1) = \frac{a+b}{c+d} = 1$ (which means $a + b = c+ d $ in this case), $f(0)=-1$ to get $f(0) = \frac{b}{d} = -1$, and $f(i)=i$ to get $f(i)=\frac{ai + b}{ci+d}= i$. Then, you'd have three equations, and you'd use them to help you solve for $a,b,c,d$. My problem is that I'm not entirely well-versed on how to solve equations with imaginary parts in them. For example, to simplify $\frac{ai+b}{ci+d} = i$, can I multiply both sides by $ci+d$? Or do I need to multiply top and bottom by the conjugate $ci-d$?

Comment: and then there's the whole matter of how you can't assume that $a,b,c,d$ are real. So yeah, sometimes people do know where to begin, but still need to see the whole problem written out so they learn how to handle things and can apply them to other similar problems. If you would be willing to do this, great.

Comment: You're off to a good start, but don't forget to set $a$ or $c$ equal to $1,$ otherwise we can't solve it! Let's say we let $c=1.$ Just like real fractions, we multiply by the denominator to clear it. Hence, you get these equations: $$a+b=1+d\\b=-d\\ai+b=(i+d)i$$ The last equation can be rewritten as: $$ai+b=-1+di.$$ Can you solve the system from there?

Comment: Minor correction: If we don't choose a non-$0$ value (such as $1$) for $a$ or $c,$ it will be a bit less straightforward to solve, since we'll have $3$ linear equations in $4$ variables, so the *best* case scenario is that we'll be able to solve for $3$ of the variables in terms of the $4$th.